# Geopandas plot all features same color

Tags: shapely, geopandas

Is there any easy way to plot all features in a GeoDataFrame as the same color, rather than the default color map?

Say I have the following geodataframe of linestrings:

```
>>> import geopandas as gpd
>>> from shapely.geometry import LineString
>>> 
>>> gdf=gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[LineString([(1,2),(4,5)]),LineString([(6,3),(7,3)]),LineString([(6,2),(8,9)])])
>>> gdf
                geometry
0  LINESTRING (1 2, 4 5)
1  LINESTRING (6 3, 7 3)
2  LINESTRING (6 2, 8 9)
>>>
```

How can I use `gdf.plot()` but have all 3 LineStrings show up colored black?

Comment: You can specify that with the color keyword: `gdf.plot(color='black')`

Comment: That did not work for me. I get the same plot if I do `gdf.plot()` or `gdf.plot(color='black')`

Comment: Ah, possibly this is fixed in the development version but not yet in the latest released version. If you do `pip install --upgrade git+git://github.com/geopandas/geopandas.git`, it should work I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since setting a single color is not yet implemented, you can simply create your own colormap with only one color.

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap    
mycolor = ListedColormap('blue')
```

For your example this would lead to

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap    

mycolor = ListedColormap('blue')        
gdf=gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[LineString([(1,2),(4,5)]),LineString([(6,3),(7,3)]),LineString([(6,2),(8,9)])])
gdf.plot(colormap=mycolor)
```

[Figure Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkepC.png)

Of course you can use any other matplotlib color.